# Datetime does not match format

Tags: python-3.x, docker, datetime, pytest, python-venv

I am running unit tests in my local environment and docker on the remote build and I have a test that fails with the following error in the docker container:

`ValueError: time data '16 Dec 2022 11:41:43 EST' does not match format '%d %b %Y %X %Z'`

The strange thing is that it passes in my local environment when I run `pytest`. I have checked the format codes given here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes and my datetime seems okay.

I don't know why the test is failing in the docker container with that error. It seems to be passing in my local env. Please help! Thanks!

EDIT:
I am trying to execute the following statement:
`datetime_string = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_string_raw, "%d %b %Y %X %Z").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%X")`

where datetime_string_raw = "16 Dec 2022 11:41:43 EST"

Comment: May be it's a culture thing, a culture that doesn't abbreviate Decemeber to "Dec" or doesn't use colon to separate time values. What culture is running in the docker container?

Comment: `%Z` not parsing `EST` would be another possibility where this can go wrong. %Z *should* work for GMT and UTC, but for arbitrary time zone name abbreviations there's on guarantee.

Comment: @FObersteiner That's why it was failing! Thanks so much! I removed the EST and the build passes using the docker container.